# Why does my Telerik report not recognise its A4 page size?

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I have just created a new Telerik report, and set its page size to A4, portrait, yet the default page width is 140mm, way short of the A4 standard 210mm.  What is going on with the report or the report designer?

Comment: Are you using the standalone designer or the VS designer? My locale is such that it uses A4 as a standart and I don't experience such problems. Tried switching to Letter - worked for me. Are you using an up to date version?

Answer (score 1):

No idea, but did it occur to you that specific product support is something Telerik provides, also through their own forum?

Comment: +1 Telerik actually has a really good forum and support system.

Comment: Yes it did, but I have also found many quality answers here from fellow Telerik users.  My normal MO is to ask in both forums.

Comment: What telerik controls are you using. Is is ASP.NET AJAX, ASP.NET MVC, WinForms, etc?